# How to detect when a window was resized with AutoHotKey?

Tags: resize, window, detect, autohotkey, tile

I need a script to detect when a window was resized with AutoHotKey.

I'm developing a script to auto tile/resize/arrange "selected" windows to fit the screen size (like auto arrange feature of Terminator terminal).

There are a few scripts (and apps) that tile opened windows (PuttyCS for example for Putty opened windows), but no one has auto-resize  feature when a window is being resized.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just make a loop that polls the dimensions of windows several times per second. Store the data in an array together with the HWND of the window. If the dimensions change, then it was resized.

Comment: Because that is active and wastes CPU cycles. A better solution is to [create a passive eventhandler](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210104-00/?p=104656) so that your code gets called by the system when and only when the window is actually moved or resized. It's harder than simply polling, but much lower profile.